# How can I decrease the value of a textfield before forwarding it to database

Tags: java, netbeans

```
 String sql = "Insert Into borrower (bid,bname,bbooknum,btitle,bcounts,dateb,dater) values  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try {
    pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);


    pst.setString(1, txtid.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txtname.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txtbooknum.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txttitle.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txtcounts.getText());
    pst.setString(6, txtdateb.getText());
    pst.setString(7, ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

    pst.execute();


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Successfully Borrowed!");

} catch (Exception e) {


}
```

My problem is that I want to reduce the txtcounts by 1 before the system submit the data to my database(sql) just like when your are borrowing a book on a library the copies are reduced by 1, hope someone can help me, thank you in advance...

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: What is txtcount? *never* do *empty catch*. Your question is unclear for me

Comment: Try transforming your textfield-String into an Integer, decrease it and transform back into a String.

Comment: txtcount is a jtextfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parsing to convert String to integer as `TimH` stated

```
String str=""+(Integer.parseInt(txtcounts.getText())-1)
pst.setString(5,str);
```

But cover your code with `try-catch` because this code can generate  Exception if input won't be string it will fier `NumberFormatException` .

Comment: this works thank you TAsk i really mean it i spent 6hrs just thinking about that youre a life saver

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the String to Int:

```
  pst.setString(5, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(txtcounts.getText())-1));
```

Better would be to catch the `NumberFormatException`, or replace all other chars:

```
 pst.setString(5, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(txtcounts.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""))-1));
```

Comment: will try hit you back later

EDIT : 

It dIdnt work .. Int cannot be converted to strIngs

Answer (score 0):

You could cast txtCounts to an Integer and reduce it by one after you're done you can cast it into a string so :

```
pst.setString(5, txtcounts.getText());
```

Becomes in your case :

```
pst.setString(5, String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(txtcounts.getText())-1));
```

or to make the code more readable:

```
int tempInt = Integer.valueOf(txtcounts.getText());
tempInt -- ;//reduces tempInt by one 
pst.setString(5, Integer.valueOf(tempInt));
```